# Compressing string to unique ID

Tags: json, encryption, compression

I have a game where users can create custom levels. I am currently generating some JSON which encodes the level, but I want an easy way for users to share levels with each other (preferably a sub-10 character ID). There is no internet connection, so all the information for the level will have to be encoded into this ID so the game can decode it and generate the level.

I've tried different kinds of encryption and compression algorithms, but I can't seem to get it to a reasonable sharable length. Hashing wouldn't work since I would need to dehash it and would need to have very low (0) collisions since it must encode that specific generated level.

Is there a better way to go about this? I realize I'm trying to cram data into 10 characters, but if I use a population of 91 different characters, that should give me 6,426,898,010,533 different possible level IDs.

Are my users cursed with long IDs, or is there a better way to compress the (preferably JSON data) into a short string? The JSON data grows larger with the size of the level. I don't care about security that much. If someone does figure out how to decode it, they would just get some useless JSON.

Comment: Have you heard of JSON web tokens?  They are encoded tokens which can store state about each user.  The state is usually called "claims," and includes things like for how long a user's session is active.  [See here](https://jwt.io) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, this is a cool idea I haven't heard of before. Unfortunately, it seems the tokens it produces are longer than some results I've had with different compression algorithms.

Comment: Yes...but you're not just looking for compression, but also encoding/encryption.

Comment: Are you suggesting to compress the generated token?

Comment: The first step is to figure out how much information you want to encode. I can't figure that out from your description.

Comment: A small level is 100-200 characters of JSON. A large level is in the thousands. Maybe JSON isn't a good way to go about it?

Comment: Could you give us a description of the structure of the level description along with the ranges of the values stored?

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried different kinds of encryption and compression algorithms, but I can't seem to get it to a reasonable sharable length. Hashing wouldn't work since I would need to dehash it and would need to have very low (0) collisions since it must encode that specific generated level.

IMHO it's all about amount of information and "compressability" of data. Using some text format (JSON, ..) only blows it up. Maybe you could just encode (base64?) some effective binary representation (+hash/checksum to check data integrity).

Regardless that whole level description could be quite large just to type over. Even compression would not help when having high entropy and there are no repeatable patterns.

Maybe you could use different transport, such as for mobile bluetooth (Infrared is not so common today) or serial for computers..

Comment: Yeah. I'd even say, take the (length, bitstream, hash), and chunk it into smaller pieces, say 10 bytes + 2 byte CRC (giving 16 base64 symbols). The user could then input 16 characters at a time, with each line validated.